# Woocommerce Product Grid/List View

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hi is there a way to enable List View in a Woocommerce theme?
from the link provided below, only the Grid View works. The List View seem inactive.

Thanks.

https://prnt.sc/wljg1d

Comment: Fix the Javascript error on your website, then it will work

Comment: @mujuonly: Bro how do i fix the error. Is there any special place to visit in my admin? Heres the link for better viewing. https://tomepreko.com/shop/